# Display PDF in Fancybox or other lightbox

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation, fancybox

HI I was wondering if there is a way to display a pdf in a light box, preferably Fancybox.

I have this page set up
http://smrtbrand.com/guidance/

If you click on new born shopping list I have it loading in a iframe but it it loads pdf as data I believe.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use Fancybox iframe

```
<a href="sample.php">This goes to iframe</a>
```

and in sample.php use Google Document Viewer

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?  url=http://smrtbrand.com/pdfs/SMRT.newbaby.chcklst.pdf&embedded=true"
style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: wait... I got it. Looks like some of the code above was getting cropped out

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, went to here http://docs.google.com/viewer
Generated the document, copied the iframe code. Then threw that on a separate page and called the fancy box using the jquery

   $(".fancyFrame").fancybox({'frameWidth' : 700, 'frameHeight': 600, 'overlayShow': true, 'hideOnContentClick': false});

Comment: dude i see it workin on this link http://smrtbrand.com/guidance/

whats the problem